# How to create a component that returns promise for react lazy?

Tags: reactjs, react-native

All the examples I looked into shows half of the story. We can import component like this
`const OtherComponent = React.lazy(() => import('./OtherComponent'));`

But how should the `OtherComponent` be written so that it will return promise ?

My `OtherComponent` fetches remote data and returns table using axios.  I don't see the custom fallback component rather the screen kind of freezes until the remote data is fetched and than after that shows table. This may be because `OtherComponent` is not returning promise.

What is the correct way to implement React Lazy ? I am working on react native .

My `OtherComponent`

```
function OtherComponent(props) {

const [indexes, setIndexes] = useState([]);
const [refreshing, setRefreshing] = useState(false);

const getRemoteData = () => {
    axios.all([
        axios.get(URL, {
            params: {
                request: INDEXES
            }
        })

    ])
        .then(axios.spread((newIndexes) => {
            setRefreshing(false);
            setIndexes(newIndexes.data);
            setDataMode('remote');
        }))

};




return (
    <ScrollView style={{ flex: 1 }}
        refreshControl={
            <RefreshControl
                refreshing={refreshing}
                onRefresh={() => {
                    setRefreshing(true);
                    getRemoteData();
                }}
                colors={[COLOR_LOSE, COLOR_PRIMARY_DARK, COLOR_GAIN]} />
        }>

        <DataTable>
            <DataTable.Header>
                <DataTable.Title>Index</DataTable.Title>
                <DataTable.Title numeric>Current</DataTable.Title>
                <DataTable.Title numeric>Change</DataTable.Title>
                <DataTable.Title numeric>%Change</DataTable.Title>
            </DataTable.Header>

            {
                indexes.map(data => <DataTable.Row key={data.index}>
                    <View style={{ flex: 1, justifyContent: 'center' }}><Text style={styles.indexName}>{data.index}</Text></View>
                    <DataTable.Cell numeric>{data.currentValue.toFixed(2)}</DataTable.Cell>
                    <ChangeText change={data.change.toFixed(2)} showIcon={false} />
                    <ChangeText change={data.perChange.toFixed(2)} showIcon={true} iconSize={20} />
                </DataTable.Row>)

            }
        </DataTable>
        <Suspense fallback={<Loading />}>
            <Chart />
        </Suspense>
    </ScrollView>
)
}

export default OtherComponent;
```

Lazy Import

```
import Loading from '../../../components/Loading';
const Subindex = React.lazy(() => import('./OtherComponent'));

function LazyIndex() {
return (
    <Suspense fallback={<Loading />} >
        <OtherComponent />
    </Suspense>
)
}
```

Comment: `OtherComponent` is just a regular component, there's nothing special about it.

Comment: You have the Suspense too, right? Can we see your code that implements both?

Comment: I have added codes. Please check.